# How to create a row matrix whose elements are the iterations of my while loop

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, while-loop

Very new to matlab and I am having difficulty with the syntax. I want to perform a while loop where every n<sup>th</sup> iteration will be the n<sup>th</sup> element of my matrix, so basically what I have in mind is this:

```
f=[];
s:=1:
while s~=10 do
   f(s):=s.^2;
   s:=s+1;
end_while
```

Is this the correct code?

Comment: Yup thats your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without the `while` loop:

```
f=[1:9].^2
```

If you want to use a loop, you can do:

```
f=[];
s=1;
while s~=10
   f(s)=s.^2;
   s=s+1;
end
```

**Edit** following Matt comment below

The code you've written contains 4 errors (three of them are of the same type):

```
s:=1;
```

to assign a value to a var use simply `=`, that is `s=1` (`:` not needed)

- to close the `while` loop, use `end` (`end_while` is not a MatLab statement)

Also, as suggested by Matt, you can use a `for` loop:

```
f=[];
for s=1:9
   f(s)=s^2
end
```

Anyway, I suggest you to use the first approach (`f=[1:9].^2`).

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: @Matt I agree with you, but the question was about using a `while` loop. Anyway, the easiest way seems the first solution I've proposed: `f=[1:9].^2` without any loop.

Comment: @Matt thank you for the suggestion. I've updated the answer accordingly.